# Does SVG in the browser support the overloaded rotate() method rotate(angle, centerX, centerY) in CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have read about a rotate transform that supports rotating around a center point with `rotate(angle, centerX, centerY)` but it does not appear to work when applied via CSS.

It works inline as an attribute:

```html
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="3" style="fill: black"/>

  <g id="arrow" style="stroke: black">
     <line x1="60" y1="50" x2="90" y2="50"/>
     <polygon points="90, 50, 85 45, 85, 55"/>
  </g>

  <use xlink:href="#arrow" transform="rotate(60, 50, 50)"/>
</svg>
```

But it does not work when applied through CSS style rule:

```css
#arrow2 {
  transform: rotate(60, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="3" style="fill: black"/>

  <g id="arrow" style="stroke: black">
     <line x1="60" y1="50" x2="90" y2="50"/>
     <polygon points="90, 50, 85 45, 85, 55"/>
  </g>

  <g id="arrow2" style="stroke: red">
     <line x1="60" y1="50" x2="90" y2="50"/>
     <polygon points="90, 50, 85 45, 85, 55"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image: CSS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property "transform" is not same for CSS and SVG. In this case, try this:

```css
#arrow2 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="3" style="fill: black"/>

  <g id="arrow" style="stroke: black">
     <line x1="60" y1="50" x2="90" y2="50"/>
     <polygon points="90, 50, 85 45, 85, 55"/>
  </g>

  <g id="arrow2" style="stroke: red">
     <line x1="60" y1="50" x2="90" y2="50"/>
     <polygon points="90, 50, 85 45, 85, 55"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, CSS `transform: rotate()` only accepts the one rotation parameter. Docs on [rotate from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate). The `transform-origin` property is also required to move the rotation point away from the center default.

My guess is that it works "inside" the SVG due to the browser using a different parser for the SVG then it does for CSS. Thus mapping the overloaded "style" to the native `SVG Transform` function. The MDN docs allude to as much:

> As of SVG2, transform is a presentation attribute, meaning it can be
>   used as a CSS property. However, be aware that there are some
>   difference in syntax between the CSS property and the attribute. See
>   the documentation for the CSS property transform for the specific
>   syntax to use in that case.

Note that the docs for [SVG Transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) allow the additional parameters on `rotate()`.